# No abre file local o carpeta compartida

Tags: html, archivo

Hola muchachos ando en un problema con esto para abrir archivos locales o carpeta compartida en red porque tengo los archivos en otro servidor con otra ip.

PRUEBA 1: AGREGANDO HTTP

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://file:\\\\192.168.20.6\\001920-2020-3-1.pdf">MI PDF</a>
```

GENERA ESTO LA ETIQUET A:
http://file//192.168.20.6/001920-2020-3-1.pdf
Al dar clic abre eso en el navegador pero no abre porque falta el ":" después del file así-> http://file://192.168.20.6/001920-2020-3-1.pdf así agregando si abre pero eso no es la idea, si no es dar clic en enlace y que se abra en el navegador.

PRUEBA 2: SIN HTTP

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:\\\\192.168.20.6\\001920-2020-3-1.pdf">MI PDF</a>
```

GENERA ESTO LA ETIQUET A:
file://192.168.20.6/001920-2020-3-1.pdf
Pero no abre al dar clic pero si copio y pego la url generada al navegador si abre normal pero eso no es la idea esa, si no es dar clic en enlace y que se abra en el navegador.

Habrá alguna forma de arreglarlo para que funcione.

Comment: No va a abrir archivos locales por seguridad, debes instalar un servidor web y usar direcciones relativas a su dirección web.

Comment: No me funcionan esas opciones